# Como evaluar nulo a variable de tipo char

Tags: c#, null, evaluación

recibo unos datos de una tabla de SQLServer, y los inserto en un objeto, una de las propiedades del objeto es de tipo `char` también es un `char` en la base de datos.

```
class Cproduct200 : Product
{
    private char parent;
    public char _parent
    {
        get { return parent; }
        set { parent = value; }
    }
}
```

A este campo puede le llegar un `Null` des de la base de datos y no se como puedo evaluarlo y darle un valor antes de asignárselo a la propiedad en caso de ser `Null`.
He intentado hacer: `_parent = char.Parse(dr["padre"].ToString())??" "` pero no me ha funcionado.

```
   articlesPare = (from DataRow dr in  dtPares.Rows
                    select new Cproduct200()
                    {
                        name = dr["DescripcionArticulo"].ToString(),
                        regular_price = decimal.Parse(dr["PrecioVenta"].ToString()),
                        _parent = char.Parse(dr["padre"].ToString())
                    }).ToList();
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Debes comparar la columna con `DBNull.Value`, algo asi como `if (dr["padre"]!=DBNull.Value) { _parent = dr["padre"].ToString();}`

Comment: Pero como puedo hacer la evaluación asignando los valores al objeto?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/221582/579895

Comment: @Pikoh A lo máximo que he llegado es a esta conclusión, pero no me funciona.
`articlesPare = (from DataRow dr in dtPares.Rows
                            select new Cproduct200()
                            {
                                name = dr["DescripcionArticulo"].ToString(),
                                _parent = DBNull.Value ? ' ' : char.Parse(dr["padre"].ToString())
                            }).ToList();`

Comment: Por que sigues probando como si `DBNull.Value` fuera null, y no lo es. Prueba en todo caso `_parent = Convert.IsDBNull(dr["padre"]) ?  ' ' : char.Parse(dr["padre"].ToString()) ;`